# phpword table cell sizes not working when using openoffice

Tags: openoffice.org, phpword

Im using PHPWord to create .doc files. When I open these files with MS Word all is fine, but when I use openoffice, the table cell sizes automatically reset and are spaced equally acoss the page.

The problem is that I use the OpenOffice headless service to convert these documents to PDF, which then also screws up the PDF files.

Really struggling since PHPWord has stopped giving support since 2011...

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

To fix the indent bug, comment lines `79` and `84` in `Shared/XMLWriter.php`.

The functions `setIndent` and `setIndentString` there are responsible for the wrong cell sizes.